# Sound sensor not working when connected to DC motor

Tags: dc, dc-motor, noise, attiny

I made a small circuit to control a DC motor with a sound sensor, using an ATtiny 85 and an L293D.

It worked on breadboard, but now that I have a prototype PCB it ceases to work. Whenever I connect the DC motor, my sound sensor reacts as if it was detecting sound non-stop. As soon as there is contact, the sound-sensor LED lights up.

I am not sure where to start. I added 10nF capacitors to the ATtiny and sound sensor, a 10uf Electrolytic and a 100nF to the motor to the battery to reduce electrical noise. I am not sure where to start to debug this.

[image: the circuit]

[image: the schematic]

Comment: What are you doing to prevent detection of the sound of the motor?  Perhaps you should replace the motor with an indicator LED and validate the implementation of the circuit.  Right now it's very hard to tell if the behavior is due to an outright circuit error, or to the breadboard version being dependent on plastic construction which may have more damping than a PCB sitting on a table next to a motor.

Comment: looks like the motor has an eccentric weight on the shaft  .... does it vibrate then it runs? ..... don't test it on a table like that ..... use a foam pad under the motor

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comments. I usually hold it between my fingers to test it so the sound is really minimal, I also tried it on a foam pad with the same result. I removed the shaft and got the same result.
I tried with the LED and got mixed result, during the first try the lighting on of the LED triggered the sound sensor (weirdly), on the second try it had a normal behavior.

Comment: Another possible cause of false positive sound detection is **electrical** noise from the motor on the power lines. You could try separating the power supplies so that the motor driver is isolated.

Comment: @loudnoises I tried to separate the supply using a breadboard without luck, but do you mean having 2 separate power supplies? As in 2 set of batteries?

Comment: Yes, if you are using batteries then use two separate batteries, one for the microcontroller and sound sensor, the other for the motor driver, physically isolated with no shared power tracks. I would also recommend moving back to the breadboard if you could get that working, and see if you can reproduce the issue to find the reason why the PCB is failing.

Comment: @loudnoises, I will try that, thanks for the answer. Although the end-goal is to have a small device, that is why I tried to have the whole system on a single battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, replacing the batterie and placing 6AA with a UBEC regulator instead of 4 fixed the problem. The previous batteries were probably a bit worn off. Thanks for your answers.